# Laravel belongsToMany with more then 3 primary keys

Tags: sql-server, laravel

Actually I'm confused for the case, which relation fits best for my case, and in my opinion the best one is to have a table with 3 primary keys.

To be more specific.

I have a Person model in one of my db's, which has structure like

```
Person:
Id,
FirstName,
LastName,
...
```

And the other model Department, which has structure mentioned below

```
Department:
Id,
Name,
Description,
...
```

And goal is to set up Editors of schedule for each department and add also admins, whioch will approve requested schedules from editors. Editors and Admins are from same Person table, and if to assume, we need to map some Persons and department with some type. 
I'm thinking about to have a mapping table with structure

```
PersonID,
DepartmentID,
Type (editor or admin)
```

And not sure, which relation fits best for this. If to have belongsToMany relation here with primary keys PersonID and DepartmentID, we will face an issue, because same Person possibly can be as editor and as admin for one single department. I have MS SQL server as a db.

Any suggestions will be appreciated

Comment: I don't unterstand your question, as you can only ever have a single primary key by definition

Comment: @Kaii Sorry, I was not clear. I'm about setting primary key using multiple columns. For example you can check such kind of example in Laravel Entrust package

          `$table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');`
            `$table->integer('role_id')->unsigned();`

            `$table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');`
            `$table->foreign('role_id')->references('id')->on('roles')
                ->onUpdate('cascade')->onDelete('cascade');`
            `$table->primary(['user_id', 'role_id']);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can define many to many relations and use wherePivot method to select by pivot table Type column:

```
// Department model
public function admins()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Person::class)->wherePivot('type', 'admin');
}

public function editors()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Person::class)->wherePivot('type', 'editor');
}

// Person model
public function departmentsWhereIsAdmin()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Department::class)->wherePivot('type', 'admin');
}

public function departmentsWhereIsEditor()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Department::class)->wherePivot('type', 'editor');
}

// Note: we use methods names without parentheses

// usage for department
$department = Department::first(); // for example
dump($department->admins);
dump($department->editors);

// usage for person
$person = Person::first(); // for example
dump($person->departmentsWhereIsAdmin);
dump($person->departmentsWhereIsEditor);
```

Comment: Please consider, that I will have an issue in this case, because it's possible, that same person for one single department will be as admin and as editor at the same time, in this case last record will be overwritten previous mapping. Am I wright ?

Comment: This is almost working answer, just for a case, that I mentioned above, I should have in migration a line for primary key like `$table->primary(['PersonID', 'DepartmentID', 'Type']);`

Comment: In that case you don't have to look at Type column so, you can define departments method without `wherePivot`